# Trouble adding Firestore to existing Firebase project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According the the documentation the new firestore database module needs to be imported separately unlike the rest of the modules that can be imported all at once with `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`?

Doing so gives the error:

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

If I remove any reference to `firebase.firestore()` this error goes away so firebase is being initialized and was working before the attempt to add Firestore.

Can someone tell me how to properly import the Firestore module?

Answer (score 2):

In my main.js file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
```

Seems to be working. Silly it was that simple.